# Change the name of keys while creating an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, solr

I have the response in the following format after doing groupby in solr query. I am using solr version 3.5

```
"grouped":{
    "channel_id":{
      "matches":48,
      "ngroups":26,
      "groups":[{
          "groupValue":"204",
          "doclist":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "channel_name":"ZeeTv",
                "channel_num":4,
                "title":"The Name",
                "channel_id":"204"
          }},
        {
          "groupValue":"166",
          "doclist":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "channel_name":"Sony",
                "channel_num":2,
                "title":"The Name",
                "channel_id":"166",
              {
                "channel_name":"Sony",
                "channel_num":2,
                "title":"The Puzzle",
                "channel_id":"166"
          }}]}}
```

I am taking the response in an array in the following way :

```
for(var chl in data.grouped.channel_id.groups) {
    config['playlist'].push(data.grouped.channel_id.groups[chl]['doclist']['docs']); 
}
```

Thus an individual array of each `groupValue` is formed. The struture of the array is:

```
"0"=>{"0"=>"value"},"1"=>{"0"=>"result1","1"=>"result2"}
```

But i want to change the key name i.e. "0","1" to the `groupValue` from the response while creating an array so that i can do `config['playlist']['166']` to check all the shows for this `channel_id` from the array. Can this be done and if so how. I am expecting the following :

```
"204"=>{"0"=>"value"},"166"=>{"0"=>"result1","1"=>"result2"}
```

Also if possible can the solr query be made such that the `channel_num` in the response comes in ascending order i.e. first result for channel_num 2 and then 4. I have done `groupby:channel_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that?

```
for(var chl in data.grouped.channel_id.groups) {
    config['playlist'][data.grouped.channel_id.groups[chl].groupValue] = data.grouped.channel_id.groups[chl]['doclist']['docs'];
}
```

Push is there to add an element at the end of an array. But any Javascript object is just a hash table, so you can use it that way.

By the way, you can make the code simpler with a `for each` :

```
for each(var chl in data.grouped.channel_id.groups) {
    config['playlist'][ch1.groupValue] = ch1['doclist']['docs'];
}
```

Comment: Your second code block is not valid javascript outside of firefox. Also, all of the for-each loops are missing a `hasOwnProperty` check.

Comment: You shouldn't use `for`...`in` on arrays.  Use `len = data.grouped.channel_id.groups.length; for (var chl=0; chl < len; ++chl )` instead.  See discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Pikrass has answered correctly... as far as ordering with `channel_num` is concerned try adding the following in your query:

```
&sort=channel_num asc
```

Comment: Cannot accept two answer at the same time so up voting you. Thanks